# mongo displays error on MAMP

Tags: mongodb, mamp

I have followed [this](http://www.davidgolding.net/mongodb/installing-mongodb-on-mamp-1-9-5.html) after installing Mongo on Mac.

On php.ini shows mongo details.

```
mongo
MongoDB Support enabled
Version     1.0.11

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mongo.allow_empty_keys  0   0
mongo.allow_persistent  1   1
mongo.auto_reconnect    1   1
mongo.chunk_size    262144  262144
mongo.cmd   $   $
mongo.default_host  localhost   localhost
mongo.default_port  27017   27017
mongo.long_as_object    0   0
mongo.native_long   0   0
mongo.utf8  1   1
```

But when I type mongo on a terminal it displays the following error.

```
sokada-macbook:bin sokada$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: test
Thu Jun 14 21:54:47 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

I thank you in advance to solve this problem.

Comment: have you checked that mongod is actually running?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to run the following in the terminal.

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Then I run mongo and give the following.

```
sokada-macbook:~ sokada$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: test
>
```

Comment: In the first part of the tutorial you linked (1. Prepare MAMP for MongoDB files), the data dirs were meant to be created under the MAMP directory .. which should have worked if you also set up the start scripts with --dbpath

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have successfully installed the Mongo support for PHP, but haven't started the actual mongod server yet.

In the [tutorial](http://www.davidgolding.net/mongodb/installing-mongodb-on-mamp-1-9-5.html) you followed, that would be Step 4. Create Startup Routines for MAMP.